# Vala compiler(valac) cannot find Lua package

Tags: 12.04, vala

The problem is very simple.

The generated .c file has `#include <lua.h>;`

`valac -C --pkg lua luatest.vala`

which should be `#include <lua52/lua.h>;`

I have found all lua headers in /usr/include/lua52,

but pkg-config for vala(c) cannot find them.

the error is
`/home/aleksandar/Programing/ewns-viewer/ewns-viewer.vala.c:8:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory`

Please help.

Comment: /home/aleksandar/Programing/ewns-viewer/ewns-viewer.vala.c:8:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @jackweirdy This is not true. For that to work, then -I/usr/include/lua52 would need to be in the CFLAGS.

Comment: @dobey didn't know that, I removed my comment to avoid future confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

How did you install liblua? If I install the `liblua50-dev` package, then `pkg-config --cflags lua50` prints the correct include path. Does running `pkg-config --cflags lua52` print the correct include path for you? I think you need to add the CFLAGS manually, as the lua.vapi in vala doesn't seem to know about what package to use for lua with pkg-config here.

I don't know what you're using for a build system exactly, but you can do this manually by running valac like so:

```
valac -X "-I/usr/include/lua52" -C --pkg lua luatest.vala
```

Comment: Unknown option -Xcc=-I/usr/include/lua52. I am using valac 0.14.I installed lua52-dev from synaptic.

Comment: valac --pkg lua luatest.vala  -X -I/usr/include/lua52
/home/aleksandar/Desktop/luatest.vala.c:7:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Comment: Installed it from where? There is no lua52-dev in Ubuntu precise, or even on quantal. There is only liblua50-dev. If lua.h is actually in /usr/include/lua52 as you stated, the command I listed should work.

Comment: There is luadev52,newest version is 5.2.0-2. Ok.I tried your command for the second time and it works.Now I do not know how to link this to glib and vala :D

Comment: There is no such lua package in the Ubuntu archives, or in Debian. You must be installing it from a PPA. Vala uses glib by default, but you will need to list the additional packages you use, using --pkg as with lua. I don't know what you're using for a build system, but Vala has excellent integration with autotools (automake and autoconf). If my answer works for you, please click "Accept" for it. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer did not help me because I does not find the liblua.so file.

Comment: @Aleksandar The command works fine here. I can't help you any further if you are using non-standard packages, which may be broken. If with my command it works, but then fails to link, that is a separate problem though, but probably related to you having a broken install of lua. The liblua.so file should come from the installing the -dev package.

Comment: Dunno.I will see that in a few days.Thanks for trying.